# DMARC authentication failed due to domain name and return path are different

Tags: email, dns, devops, dkim, dmarc

DMARC authentication failed due to domain name and return path are different

We utilize **example@primary.com** to send emails, with its return path configured to another email, **example@secondary.com**. Our testing of the DMARC policy for **example@primary.com** indicates a failed status.

We have added following record in DNS

```
default._domainkey.primary.com    v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
```

Kindly offer an appropriate resolution for addressing this issue.

Comment: Probably best to ask this question over at the ServerFault forum as StackOverflow is meant for programming related questions. And, if your going to, it would help if you added some relevant DMARC report records to illustrate your issues.